# Periodicity of an integer function

Tags: real-analysis

I know that $y = \tan\left(x\right)$ is a periodic function whose period $T$ is an irrational number $\left(\pi\right)$. Also, the range of the function is an infinite set.
Now I wonder that if $y = \mathrm{f}\left(x\right)$ ( defined on $N$ to $N$ ) is periodic whose period $T$ is a rational number then will the set $A = \left\{\mathrm{f}\left(n\right)\right\}$, where $n$ is a natural number, must be a finite set ?.

Although I think that $A$ must be finite but can there be a counterexample of the claim or the proof of its correctness ?.

Comment: "rational" period here surely means "integer".  In any case, if $\frac mn$ is a period, so is $m$.  But then $f$ is completely determined by $\{f(0), \cdots , f(m-1)\}$

Comment: $\tan$ period is $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ has period $p\in\mathbb{N}$ then we have
$$f(x)=f(x+p)$$
For all $x\in\mathbb{N}$ by definition. Hence
$$A=\{f(0),f(1),...,f(p-1)\}$$
$$\therefore 1\le|A|\le p$$
So $A$ is a finite set.